# Dev C++ HMENU (File > Exit)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I want to make something like on your internet browser. It will have a File then an exit at the bottom of the list. So I want to have it like that where it exits the program. (and like Dev C++ and any other program [I am not programming a web browser])

Ok here is my code please help:

```
#define ID_Exit 1

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch (message)           
   {
       case WM_CREATE:{

            HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
            HMENU hFile = CreateMenu();

            AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFile, "File");

            AppendMenu(hFile, MF_STRING, ID_Exit, "Exit");

            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);

            break;
    }


    case WM_COMMAND:{

         if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_Exit){                                   

         void exit ( int status );

         }

         break;
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Windows function [DestroyWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to destroy the main window:

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_Exit) {
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper exiting sequence for Win32 applications (from the lack of any library calls in your snippet I guess what you do is plain Win32) is described here: [Using Windows - Destroying a Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#destroying_win).

Calling `exit` is a bad idea, because it would immediately kill your application and does not clean up, save or do anything that might have to be done when your window is closed.